# Regex look between two strings look behind?

Tags: regex

I am trying to search between two Strings, starting from the second string looking backwards.  Is this possible?

For example:  I have a string 
"If the quick brown dog jumps over the **lazy** red dog, then..."

I want to find the characters between "the" and "red dog".
I am expecting to find " **lazy** ".

With my current regex, I am getting too many characters.

```
(?<=the)(.*)(?=red dog)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a non-greedy quantifier:

```
(?<=the)(.*?)(?=red dog)
```

This will change the behavior of the expression so that the inner group will match only as few characters as needed to satisfy the pattern.

However, I should point out that using lookarounds is probably not necessary this this case. You could simply use a pattern like this:

```
.*the(.*?)red dog
```

And extract the relevant capture group. The first `.*` is greedy, meaning the pattern will match the last `the` it can find in the string which satisfies the pattern.

Here's a working example in C#:

```
var input = "If the quick brown dog jumps over the lazy red dog, then...";
var match = Regex.Match(input, ".*the(.*?)red dog");
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value); // lazy
```

Comment: Not sure the first part of your answer will work - based on how regex parsing works, I'd still expect that to capture the long string rather than just "lazy". See [here](https://www.debuggex.com/r/EehaH_l2_t2qsRBZ). Second part will work, if extracting capture groups is suitable for him/her (although it will also capture the spaces around the word *lazy*)

Comment: Could you provide the regex with capture groups?

Comment: @newuser Without knowing what language / platform you're using, it probably won't be relevant, however, see my updated answer for a solution in C#.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=the)(.*?)(?=red)
```

it matches the least possible characters between those words, but `.` matches everything, maybe

```
(?<=the)([a-z ]*?)(?=red dog)
```

would help you to match only letters and space character

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
(?:the)(.*)(?:red dog)
```

and read the group: $1